# Using too much memory for simple XML file changer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, memory

I've written a XML changer in C# which compares the values of 2 XML files and makes them equal. I have done it in a quite lazy way because I don't know what kind of differences to expect between the files.

Here's the code:

```
    public static void ChangeNode(XDocument xdocument1, XDocument xdocument2, XElement bigNode1, XElement bigNode2)
    {
        if(bigNode1.Elements().ToList().Count < bigNode2.Elements().ToList().Count)
        {
            bigNode1.AddBeforeSelf(bigNode2);
            bigNode1.Remove();
            IsEqual = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(bigNode1.Value != bigNode2.Value)
            {
                bigNode1.AddBeforeSelf(bigNode2);
                bigNode1.Remove();
                IsEqual = false;
            }
        }

        if(!IsEqual)
        { 
            xdocument1.Save(CoreForm.File1, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
            xdocument2.Save(CoreForm.File2, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
        }
    }
```

How can I not use nearly 3GB of memory while changing a 25MB file to a 125MB file? Does it have something to do with the way I change the first file?

Comment: What does `makes them equal` mean? What problem is this code trying to solve?

Comment: You don't need to do `ToList().Count` - you can just use `.Count()`. Doing `ToList()` will make a copy of all the elements. I realise that may cause Resharper warnings about "multiple enumeration" but I think you can safely ignore those warnings in this scenario.

Comment: I have 2 xml files. One is right the other is wrong. I compare both of them and make the wrong one the same as the right one. The problem here is that I am using too much memory while changing the wrong one

Comment: Why not just use `File.Copy()`?

Comment: I could have just made xdocument1 = xdocument2 and save the file but that's no fun. The guy supervising my internship said I'm supposed to compare the files and change the differences.

Comment: On an unrelated note - you're reinventing the wheel. There already is a library for xml diff written on .NET - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx (its part of the gui tool).

Comment: My supervisor told me specifically NOT to use that library

Answer (score 2):

Can't see how whats you are doing in this mehod could result in 3gb of ram utilized.
But for very large xml files its not recommended to use the XDocument as its loading all of it to memory, instead use the XmlReader and read it in chunks.
Also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx) is a very good article regarding improving xml performance.